# Many-to-Many duplicates

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a Laravel application and I have many to many relationship as follows:

I have authors table, writings table and author_writing table. The author_writing table has an extra field called role_id which contains the Id of the role the author had in that book such as, co-author, editor...etc.
I want to get all the writings of an author and also all the roles of an author in a book: What i'm currently getting is this:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "book_name": "xyz",
        .
        .
        .
        "pivot": {
            "writing_id": 4,
            "author_id": 4,
            "role_id": 1
        },
    },
    {
        "id":1,
        "book_name": "xyz",
        .
        .
        .
        "pivot": {
            "writing_id": 4,
            "author_id": 4,
            "role_id": 2
        },
    },
    {
        "id":1,
        "book_name": "xyz",
        .
        .
        .
        "pivot": {
            "writing_id": 4,
            "author_id": 4,
            "role_id": 4
        },
    },
]
```

I'm getting this result by calling:

```
    public function writings(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Writing::class, 'author_writing', 'author_id', 'writing_id')
        ->withPivot([
            'role_id' 
        ]);
    }
```

So the writing entries are duplicated because the author has more than one role, so if the author has three roles, then the same writing is shown three times, and the only difference is the role_id in the pivot.
Hoe can show something like the following instead:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "book_name": "xyz",
        .
        .
        .
        "pivot": {
            "writing_id": 4,
            "author_id": 4,
            "role_id": [1,2, 4]
        },
    },
]
```

So only one entry but the role_id contains all the roles the author has in a writing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
public function writings(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(Writing::class, 'author_writing', 'author_id', 'writing_id')
    ->withPivot(['role_id'])
    ->selectRaw('DISTINCT Author.*, Author_Writing.*, Writing.*');
}
```

See an example here: https://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, i got SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column author_writing

Comment: could it be that you must name it author_writings with an s? I don't know how you named your tables exactly.

Comment: No not really, the data returned is correct, but there must be additional step taken to remove duplications

Comment: Updated my answer. Maybe you can avoid duplicates if you using selectRaw -> Distinct.

Comment: Thank you, but the output is quite different and i can't even see the rest of the attributes

Comment: Updated my code above. Just do DISTINCT Author.*, Author_Writing.*, Writing.*
So you should see all fields in return.
Please check it as answered or upvote if you are satisfied. So I will get some Points. THX

Comment: No unfortunately, that didn't work. I just decided to go over all the roles of each writing and then create an object with the writing ID and the roles